# Can I use Stripe as payment gateway for my iOS App?

Tags: ios

I'm building an iphone application, can I use "Stripe" as the payment to collect the customer's payment card details? If I use the "Stipe" would Apple reject my app? Would Apple make service charges for the transactions?

Answer (score 3):

I think the answer shouldn't be a plain NO. Actually that depends on what you intend to sell.

1. If its any digital content which can be sold using in App purchase then for sure apple will not allow any third party payment system to do the job for you.
2. If you want to sell physical goods like shirts, watches etc. then Apple will not restrict you from using third party payment system.

I myself haven't used Stripe yet but had a good time with PayPal so this might be helpful to you.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Still I've a query, actually I'm developing app for  car advertisement from the customer who sell the cars, so can I use Stripe?

Comment: As cars can not be sold using in App Purchase, I see no issues in using Stripe. I hope it's working is similar to PayPal.

Comment: Very helpful. Would be grateful to u!

Comment: Again, I've a query. Would Apple will collect charges for every transactions (i.e in percentage of the amount that will be transacted using Stripe).?

Comment: @Yogi hi i have to cell some audio can you suggest me any payment gateway for implementing this

Comment: @BlueBerry: No. They won't.

Comment: @Anonymous: As I already quoted in my answer any digital media can't be sold using any payment gateway. The only option is in App purchase. Actually they might restrict you from selling songs using an iOS app and may suggest you to use 'iTunes Music Store'.

Answer (score 2):

No, you can't.
Quote from [Apple Review Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/appstore/resources/approval/guidelines.html#purchasing-currencies):

> Apps utilizing a system other than the In-App Purchase API (IAP) to purchase content, functionality, or services in an App will be rejected